# How to get secret values from paged.SecretItemPaged type object

Tags: python, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk-python

I would like to get the Secret value from given SecretID using Python API's. 
I have folowing code. On the last line I am trying to get the SECRET_VERSION using get_secret_versions function. The function returns SecretItemPaged type of Object. Can someone please help to to retrieve secret_version from this objet.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultClient
    from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
    import pprint
    #from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import 
    ServicePrincipalCredentials



credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
      client_id = 'XXX',
      secret = 'XXX',
      tenant = 'XXX'
)

client = KeyVaultClient(credentials)

    VAULT_URL='https://xxxxxxx.vault.azure.net'
    SECRET_ID='https://xxxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/2345mat'
    SECRET_VERSION= client.get_secret_versions(VAULT_URL , SECRET_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

SecretItemPaged is an iterator of objects, following the Python protocol for this:
https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable
https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator

That being said, you can then use a `list` to consume it, or a `next` call until you get a `StopIteration` object, etc.

Simplest way would be to consume it as a list:

```
list(client.get_secret_versions(VAULT_URL , SECRET_ID))
```